# Can't connect spring boot to postgres k8s statefulset

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I am deploying an application for the first time on Kubernetes. I want to deploy a postgreSQL statefulset and a simple replicaset of spring boot pods. I created a headless service that will be attached to the following statefulset.

```
    # Headless Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ecom-db-h
spec:
  ports:
  - targetPort: 5432
    port: 80
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: ecom-db
---
# PostgreSQL StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: ecomdb-statefulset
  labels:
    app: ecom-db
spec:
  serviceName: ecom-db-h
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql-db
  replicas: 2
  template:
    # Pod Definition
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: postgres:13
          ports:
            - name: postgres
              containerPort: 5432
         # volumeMounts:
          #  - name: ecom-db
           #   mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: ecommerce
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: <password>
      #volumes:
       # - name: ecom-db
        #  persistentVolumeClaim:
         #   claimName: ecom-pvc
```

And here is the replicaset I created for the spring boot application pods :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: ecom-server
  labels:
    app: ecom-server
    tier: backend
spec:
  # modify replicas according to your case
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: backend
  template:
    # Pod definition
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ecom-server
        type: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ecommerce-server
        image: <my.private.repo.url>/spring-server:kubernetes-test
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
          - name: regcred
```

I am using the default namespace and here is the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ecom-db-h.default.svc.cluster.local/ecommerce?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

But my spring boot containers always exit with the following error :

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ecom-db-h.default.svc.cluster.local
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 136 common frames omitted
```

This means that either the replicaset is not able to find the headless service, or my headless service is not connected to the statefulset pods at all. Did I miss something in the YAML files ? Or am I using the headless service in the wrong way ?

---

**Update:**

Thanks to @Thomas and @harsh-manvar I understood that the headless service is not meant to connect to the databases. Instead, I should use a normal ClusterIP service. The problem is I did that and I am still getting the same error. Here is my new YAML files :

application.properties modification:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/ecommerce?useSSL=false
```

statefulset.yaml modified

```
# ClusterIP service instead of the headless service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: pgql
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: db
---
# PostgreSQL StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: db-sts
  labels:
    app: db-sts
spec:
  serviceName: db-svc
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  replicas: 2
  template:
    # Pod Definition
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: postgres:13
          ports:
            - name: postgres
              containerPort: 5432
         # volumeMounts:
          #  - name: ecom-db
           #   mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: ecommerce
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: mss#123
      #volumes:
       # - name: ecom-db
        #  persistentVolumeClaim:
         #   claimName: ecom-pvc
```

Here is the new error :

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 136 common frames omitted
```

My statefulset pods are running smoothly and the service is created :

```
NAME                      READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/db-sts   2/2     26m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/db-svc       ClusterIP   10.108.39.189   <none>        5432/TCP   26m
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    30m

NAME                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
db-sts-0            1/1     Running            0               26m
db-sts-1            1/1     Running            0               26m
ecom-server-5jbs2   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (44s ago)     25m
ecom-server-rtpmg   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (4m46s ago)   25m

NAME         ENDPOINTS                           AGE
db-svc       10.244.1.48:5432,10.244.2.85:5432   18h
```

---

**Second Update :**

After running an alpine-shell container in a pod to check on the DNS resolving, I performed an "nslookup db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local" and I got this :

```
nslookup db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.107.101.52
```

which means the service does exist and it can be reached from this container. What's strange is when I performed the pgsql command to try to connect to the postgres database server, I got no response at all and the command did not even exit. Here is the error

```
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - The connection attempt failed.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
        ... 122 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 136 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution :

**Original Post:**
First I need to use the ClusterIP service and not the headless service.

**Solution to Update :**
It was the firewall blocking the requests between the pods inside my serves. That is why I was getting the error SQLState: 08001. Disabling the firewall solved the problem. Also I needed to specify the port in the application.properties. Because I got used to not specify the port 80 with HTTP connections, I thought that was the case for the postgres connection to the database, but I needed to specify the port :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:80/ecommerce?useSSL=false
```

It would be a better practise to change the service port to the default postgres server port: 5432

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a headless service is to not provide a DNS record and provide internal load balancing.

A headless service can be used to query the endpoints and handle them separately.

To fix your issue create a regular service.

Comment: The problem is resolved, I posted the answer and you helped me. Thank you so much. But I am still confused on how will the spring boot forward the "write" requests to the postgres master pod if I don't specify the headless service. If I type the ClusterIP instead, it is possible that it will modify/insert the records in one of the slaves ( slave n ); and therefore the master and the slaves x<n won't get the record since they don't get any replication from the slave n. So how do I tell my spring boot application to forward the write requests to the headless service that points to the master ?

Answer (score 1):

Headless service won't give you DNS record you should be any of ClusterIP or NodePort or LoadBalancer

> A headless service is a service with a service IP but instead of
> load-balancing it will return the IPs of our associated Pods. This
> allows us to interact directly with the Pods instead of a proxy. It's
> as simple as specifying None for .spec.clusterIP and can be utilized
> with or without selectors - you'll see an example with selectors in a
> moment.

Read more about headless serivce at : https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8

you can follow below YAML file which is creating the serivce type : **ClusterIP**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  ports:
  - name: pgql
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: postgres
---
apiVersion: apps/v1  
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: "postgres"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:9.5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-data
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          subPath: pgdata
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: root
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: kong
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: postgres-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - "ReadWriteOnce"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment/blob/main/postgres.yaml

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't the serviceName attached to the statefulset be a headless service ?

Comment: you should be using the service type ClusterIP if your application wants to connect with Postgres. headless service will give you IP of POD and your application has to connect to POD on that IP which might get changed with time if pod restart or crash so best practice to use service name with clusterIP type.

Comment: you can checkout : https://medium.com/swlh/discovering-running-pods-by-using-dns-and-headless-services-in-kubernetes-7002a50747f4

Comment: here is good example also in code : https://medium.com/swlh/discovering-running-pods-by-using-dns-and-headless-services-in-kubernetes-7002a50747f4 you need to use the IP instead of service name which is bad practice.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will defenitely check out these links. Can you please see the question again ? I edited it with the new modifications I applied but I am still getting no result. I belive aside from my misunderstanding of the headless service concept, I am not paying attention to the labels attached to the resources I am creating.

Comment: what error now you getting can you please share that, yaml is looking good your pod is up and running ?

Comment: I just added the status of the pods, which are running as well as the logs of the new error on the question post. the spring boot containers still can't find the database containers. I am using alpine Docker images by the way, which I hear that they have some problems related to DNS resolving. Maybe that's the reason ?

Comment: yes that could be issue i would recommend checking this issue by starting busybox container and trying connecting using cli it's working or not. here we go : https://gist.github.com/so0k/860b570276a86adc38b75cb859bf4c16

Comment: How are you providing the changed application properties?

Comment: Thank you @HarshManvar . I used the busybox container and tried to connect to the postgres database through the service from there but there is no response after typing the password. I also modified my image from alpine to ubuntu but the problem remains the same, so I believe there is something wrong with my Kubernetes setup maybe ?

Comment: that's weird won't be any issue with the K8s ideally however you can check the logs of pod if any error is there.

Comment: The problem is resolved, I posted the answer and you helped me. Thank you so much. But I am still confused on how will the spring boot forward the "write" requests to the postgres master pod if I don't specify the headless service. If I type the ClusterIP instead, it is possible that it will modify/insert the records in one of the slaves ( slave n ); and therefore the master and the slaves x<n won't get the record since they don't get any replication from the slave n. So how do I tell my spring boot application to forward the write requests to the headless service that points to the master ?